# Check if element fits on the screen

Tags: android, ios, titanium

I have added a view to my app defined as follows:

```
Ti.UI.createView({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: '50%'
    height: '460dp',
    backgroundColor: 'red'
});
```

What I want to find out is whether the above view fits on the screen. I.e. whether the user's screen is tall enough to totally display my entire view. I tried it in the following way:

```
function getPixels(dp) {
    return (dp + (Ti.Platform.displayCaps.dpi / 160));
}

alert(460); // 920
alert(Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight); // 1136
```

Which seems about right on the iphone simulator. However when running that exact same code on my android device I get the result:

screenheight: 1200
height of the view: 690

Which doesn't seem correct, because the view with the red background takes almost as much space on the iphone simulator as on my android device.

Is there any way to get consistent results on all devices (ios and android). Or is there some other way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to support all sizes, why don't you set your height to a % value as well?

In answer to your question, the main thing you need to consider is that`Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight` returns values *in platform-specific units*; so pixels on Android and density-independent pixels (dip) on iOS. Since you are setting your view height with density independent pixels, you instead want to convert these platform units to density independent and platform independent units.

I usually just use the [measurement library provided](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Alloy.builtins.measurement) by Titanium and Alloy.

```
var measurement = require('alloy/measurement');
var dpHeight = measurement.pxToDP(Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight);
if(460 < dpHeight) {
    alert('Fits');
} else {
    alert("does not fit');
}
```

But really I find it much easier to just use relative layouts with percentage values.

Another way to figure out if the view is in bounds (after the fact) is to just add a [`postlayout` event listener,](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-rect) when this event is fired it means layout bounds have been calculated in system units and are now accesible:

```
view.addEventListener('postlayout', function(e) {
    if(view.rect.height + view.rect.y > Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight) {
        alert('Does not fit")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To get constant results of width and height properties between platforms you have to add

```
<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dip</property>
```

to tiapp.xml and provide sizes as plain numbers:

```
Ti.UI.createView({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 50,
    height: 460,
});
```